# Why global variable is empty in AppFilter (logging.basicConfig)?

Tags: python, logging, global-variables

I use Python and Logging facility for Python.

I have config.py:

```
MY_VARIABLE = ''
```

I have main.py:

```
from log import *
from config import MY_VARIABLE

for i in range(3):
    global MY_VARIABLE
    print(f"main.py Old: '{MY_VARIABLE}'")
    MY_VARIABLE = i
    print(f"main.py New: '{MY_VARIABLE}'")
    
    logging.info("The process is running...")
```

I have log.py:

```
import logging
from config import MY_VARIABLE


class AppFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        global MY_VARIABLE
        print(f"log.py MY_VARIABLE:{MY_VARIABLE}")
        record.my_variable = MY_VARIABLE
        return True

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s (%(my_variable)s) > %(message)s',
    datefmt='%H:%M:%S'
)
logging.getLogger('').addFilter(AppFilter())
```

I get:

```
main.py Old: ''
main.py New: '0'
log.py MY_VARIABLE:''
main.py Old: '0'
main.py New: '1'
log.py MY_VARIABLE:''
main.py Old: '1'
main.py New: '2'
log.py MY_VARIABLE:''
14:23:28 INFO file №  > The process is running...
14:23:28 INFO file №  > The process is running...
14:23:28 INFO file №  > The process is running...
```

Why variable **MY_VARIABLE** is empty in log.py? **How to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `main.py` executes the line of code `MY_VARIABLE = i`, this *rebinds* that variable name to a brand new object. The connection to the original import is lost.

Do it this way instead:

```
import config
config.MY_VARIABLE = <something>
```